# Select first item shown into a treeTableView in JavaFX 8

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a `TreeTableView` control with several items. The user can move with the side scroll bar to any part of the table. How can I know which is the first item that the table shows? I mean, the first item we see. I have been going through the methods offered by this control and I have seen that `scrollTo` shows an item according to an order number that we specify but I have not found anything that is something like `getFirstItemShown`. I imagine that for a `TableView` control it should work the same, right? I'm using JavaFX 8.

Comment: JavaFX version?

Comment: If you're using JavaFX 9+, and you're using the default skins, you could access the desired information via the [`VirtualFlow`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/skin/VirtualFlow.html). But there's no public, guaranteed-to-always-work API that provides the functionality you want.

Comment: Two people, neither of them you, have edited your question to state you're using JavaFX 8. Before the edit the question gave no indication as to what version of JavaFX you are using. If you are using a different version, please [edit] your question to correct it.

Comment: @Slaw (aware that you can't know :) - just wondering why they did edit to include fx8? There's no hint in the question and fx8 is very much outdated ... the first edit should have been rejected, IMO

Comment: @kleopatra Agreed. I tried to reject it...

Comment: The version is OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for fun:

(note that if there are cut lines it can choose the next row, and the first row is sometimes hidden under the Column)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        primaryStage.setTitle("Tree View Sample");
        TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<String> ("Inbox");
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);

        for (int i = 1; i < 888; i++) {
            TreeItem<String> item = new TreeItem<String> ("Message" + i);
            rootItem.getChildren().add(item);
        }
        TreeTableColumn<String, String> column = new TreeTableColumn<>("Column");
        column.setPrefWidth(150);
        column.setCellValueFactory((CellDataFeatures<String, String> p) -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(
                p.getValue().getValue()));
        TreeTableView<String> treeTableView = new TreeTableView<>(rootItem);
        treeTableView.getColumns().add(column);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(treeTableView, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();

        Platform.runLater(()->{
            ScrollBar verticalBar = (ScrollBar) treeTableView.lookup(".scroll-bar");
            verticalBar.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                    int currentRow = 0;
                    if(newValue.doubleValue()<1){
                        currentRow =(int)((newValue.doubleValue()*treeTableView.getExpandedItemCount())-(newValue.doubleValue()*verticalBar.getVisibleAmount())*treeTableView.getExpandedItemCount());
                    }else {
                        currentRow =(int)(treeTableView.getExpandedItemCount()-verticalBar.getVisibleAmount()*treeTableView.getExpandedItemCount());
                    }
                    System.out.println(currentRow);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```